# Mostrar campos se diferente de 0 (zero)

Tags: php, html

Como mostrar os campos de cada registro na tabela , se o campo produtoN  for diferente de zero ?

```
    </td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $customer['produto2']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customer['serial2']; ?></td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $customer['produto3']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customer['serial3']; ?></td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $customer['produto4']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customer['serial4']; ?></td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $customer['produto5']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customer['serial5']; ?></td> 
    <tr>                
</tr>
```

Comment: Ou seja, não quero a impressão (display) se produto2 não houver, se produto3 não houver, sucessivamente.
Já tentei encaixar um if else, mas sem sucesso, em função da estrutura do display !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o `produtoN` existe no array com o `isset()` e também verificar se é diferente de 0:

```
<?php if(isset($customer['produto4']) && $customer['produto4'] != 0) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $customer['produto4']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $customer['serial4']; ?></td> 
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito grato pela ajuda. Com variações no isset consigo os resultados que quero para cada campo.
Sucesso !

Comment: Quanto mais aprendo, descubro que preciso estudar mais, a cada dia.
Grato a todos !